# Template argument deduction for inheriting specializations

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, specialization

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/z/UDWHDA) code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename > struct BB { };
template < >          struct BB<float> : BB<int> { };
                      struct DD : BB<float> { };

template < typename... Args >
void ff(BB<Args...>) { }

int main()
{
    ff(BB<float>{});
    ff(DD{}); // FAILS! 'BB<Args ...>' is an ambiguous base class of 'DD'
    return 0;
}
```

The call of `ff(DD{})` fails to compile, as `gcc-8.3` doesn't want to pick one from `BB<float>` and `BB<int>` (`clang` does the same). But `BB<float>` *isa* `BB<int>`, so why just `BB<float>` can't be picked?!

The questions are: is this according to the standard and is there a workaround while defining `ff` or `BB` to help `gcc-8.3` to pick `BB<float>`?

Comment: Looks like it is a gcc bug. For what it's worth, icc19 compiles fine. I see no reason why DD should not be convertable to `BB<float>`.

Comment: @SergeyA: Why should the compiler be able to deduce this correctly? How, rather?

Comment: Same way it does here: https://godbolt.org/z/bPYajH

Comment: @L.F. what is the other thing it can be deduced to? (Apart from `BB<float>`)?

Comment: @SergeyA: Clang chokes on OPs example. Is that also a compiler bug?

Comment: @AndyG yes, I have recently seen a lot of confirmed compiler bugs which are exactly the same in both CLang and gcc. icc, on the other hand, is always exceptional - it normally shares no bugs from clang/gcc, and instead has it's owns

Comment: @SergeyA: I think icc also chokes on OPs example.

Comment: @SergeyA: MSVC, however, handles it

Comment: @AndyG icc19 certainly handles OPs case correctly. Just follow the link and choose icc19

Comment: @SergeyA: Ah, so it does. Apologies.

Comment: @SergeyA: I think that [temp.deduct.type] agrees with you that it should be possible to deduce the template arguments.

Comment: @AndyG for what it's worth I also believe so, but I really don't have the energy enough to put it all together and provide a conclusive answer right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue was the subject of [CWG 2303](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2303). The committee decided to add wording "preferring 'nearer' base classes" and this wording was [added to the working draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/a429e4336e7799e58145c82c0944ec98e6e472da). So, in C++20, your example should instantiate `ff<float>(BB<float>)` whereas in C++17, it is ambiguous.

Of course, the workaround if your compiler doesn't support "C++2a" mode or if C++2a mode hasn't implemented this change yet, is to add an overload of `ff` that takes `D`.

Comment: Thank you for providing the correct answer so I could delete my version.